# What happens when a type containing a lambda gets assigned?

Tags: c++, lambda

Say I have some sort of type wrapping up a function, maybe a lambda function:

```
template<typename Function>
  struct my_struct
{
  Function f;

  my_struct(const Function &f) : f(f) {}
};
```

What happens when an instance of this type is assigned? My understanding is that lambdas are immutable, and have deleted assignment operators.

Yet, when I assign to an object this type in the code snippet below, no error is emitted:

```
// a structure which contains a function;
// possibly a lambda function
template<typename Function>
  struct my_struct
{
  Function f;

  my_struct(const Function &f) : f(f) {}

  // XXX adding this assignment operator causes an error
  //my_struct &operator=(const my_struct &other)
  //{
  //  f = other.f;
  //  return *this;
  //}
};

template<typename Function>
my_struct<Function> make_struct(const Function &f)
{
  return my_struct<Function>(f);
}

int main()
{
  // create some lambda
  auto lambda = [](int x){return x;};

  // make a struct containing a copy of the lambda
  auto x = make_struct(lambda);

  // try to assign to the struct, which
  // presumably assigns to the enclosed lambda
  x = make_struct(lambda);

  return 0;
}
```

Adding the commented-out assignment operator yields an error, as expected:

```
$ g++-4.6 -std=c++0x test.cpp
test.cpp: In member function ‘my_struct<Function>& my_struct<Function>::operator=(const my_struct<Function>&) [with Function = main()::<lambda(int)>, my_struct<Function> = my_struct<main()::<lambda(int)> >]’:
test.cpp:34:25:   instantiated from here
test.cpp:13:5: error: use of deleted function ‘main()::<lambda(int)>& main()::<lambda(int)>::operator=(const main()::<lambda(int)>&)’
test.cpp:27:18: error: a lambda closure type has a deleted copy assignment operator
```

So, is it possible to create assignable types with lambda member variables?  This seems like a reasonable thing to want to try.  Consider combining a lambda with `boost::transform_iterator`, for example.

Comment: I don't know much about moving yet, but is it possible that they can be moved but not copied? You may already know the answer to that, but I'm not knowledgeable about move-ctors so if you do, please tell.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but introducing a move operator didn't seem to change the error message.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're close. A lambda has an implicit copy-constructor and may have — depending on the captured values — an implicit move-constructor. It has a deleted copy-assignment operator.

In other words, you may construct it, but you may not assign it. If you're looking for a generic function object, you want to use `std::function<>`. It emulates functions as first-class values.

---

Note that immutable is different from assignable.  When a lambda is called mutable, that means its function-call body can modify the members of the lambda (i.e., the function is not `const`):

```
int i = 0;

auto okay = [=](int x) mutable { i += x; };
auto error = [=](int x) { i += x; };
```

Each of these is copy-constructable and non-assignable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  It's too bad assignment is deleted -- it does seem to make lambda incompatible with ```boost::transform_iterator```, at least with its current implementation.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35412456/554283) for other workarounds (using std::ref, the proposed Boost Fit library, and the proposed Boost Range Extensions library).

Comment: but how then can std::function make a copy of the lambda?