# boost::function_output_iterator constructed from lambda function is not assignable

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, lambda

Consider the following code snippet:

```
auto f = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
auto it = boost::make_function_output_iterator(f);
decltype(it) it2 = it;  // Ok, copied
it2 = it;  // Does not compile, cannot assign!
```

The problem is, `function_output_iterator` constructed in this way is not assignable, and thus does not satisfy the [Iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) concept, which requires type to be [CopyAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable).

This is not a bug, since [boost Function Output Iterator documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html) clearly [says](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html#function-output-iterator-requirements):

> UnaryFunction must be Assignable and Copy Constructible.

While assignment operator of a [lambda function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) is deleted:

```
ClosureType& operator=(const ClosureType&) = delete;
```

So this behaviour is technically correct, but for me is somewhat unexpected. I think it is a perfectly reasonable desire to construct `function_output_iterator` given a closure produced by lambda function. It seems inconvenient to me why this use case causes a problem.

Hm, ok, this StackOverflow, so I have to ask some question :) Here it is: how to workaround this? How to obtain a correct iterator given a closure, which acts like `function_output_iterator`?

And another one: does it worth to make a proposal or a bug report to boost?

Comment: It works if you use `std::function` instead of  `auto`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e92b2ce686b4dff

Comment: Another alternative if you don't need to capture anything: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41d7a423016c38e7

Comment: @jrok good comment, should be answer.

Comment: @cv_and_he good comment, should be answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply save the closure in a `std::function`:

```
std::function<void(int)> f = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
auto it = boost::make_function_output_iterator(f);
```

[**Test snippet.**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e92b2ce686b4dff)

Comment: Notably this answer adds virtual function call overhead.

Answer (score 14):

Another option, if you are sure the closure will outlive the iterator and its copies, wrap it with `std::ref`:

```
auto f = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
auto it = boost::make_function_output_iterator(std::ref(f));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdd3825e8639db9f).

And here is a proposal for a boost utility class fixing this particular problem: [boost::regular](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/faithandbrave/OvenToBoost/blob/master/libs/range/doc/html/range_extension/reference/range_utilities/regular.html)

See the corresponding discussion in [boost mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/iterator-function-output-iterator-constructed-from-a-lambda-function-is-not-assignable-td4683493.html).

Comment: this is perfect

Comment: By the way, I think C++20 makes lambda captures assignable (unless captured types aren't, of course).