# How to combine back_inserter with a transformation, C++

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, c++14

How can I wrap an OutputIterator such as `back_inserter_iterator` with a transformation? 
Consider

```
std::vector<double> xx;
std::vector<double> yy;
std::vector<double> diff;
auto ba = std::back_inserter(diff);
std::set_difference(xx.begin(), xx.end(), yy.begin(), yy.end(), ba);
```

I would like to apply a free function `f(double)` or `g(std::vector<double>::iterator)` before pushing back to the diff vector:

Specifically, how can I store the addresses of the diff elements (or iterators) instead of the elements themeselves.

```
std::vector<double&> diff;
auto baAdr = ??? std::back_inserter( ??? (diff)); 
std::set_difference(xx.begin(), xx.end(), yy.begin(), yy.end(), baAdr);
```

For performance reasons (the real data is big) I do not want to construct a temporary vector and `std::transform` from it. It would also not work for non-copyable, movable types.

I can use boost.

Comment: `boost::function_output_itetator` perhaps?

Comment: @JohanLundberg Did you look at the [example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_output_iterator.html)? Like, you literally want `make_function_output_iterator([&](double d){ diff.push_back(f(d)); })`

Comment: I do not think set_difference will give the addresses of the elements to the output iterator. Maybe if you take a reference in the `operator=()` of  `*iterator`, but I am not sure this is guaranteed, i.e. you may get the address of a temporary.

Comment: @PaulR I don't think copying the actual values is an allowed implementation. And, only a subset of types can be copied.

Comment: I just had a look, in libstdc++ 7.2 there is no temporary. You are right, extra copying would be inefficient in general, so it cannot be used in the general implementation. As to non copyable types, well, the standard says: "Copies the elements...", although with the right operator= you are good to go :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `boost::function_output_iterator`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<double> xx;
    std::vector<double> yy;
    std::vector<const double*> diff;  // const pointers, or else you
                                      // need a const_cast in lambda

    std::set_difference(xx.begin(), xx.end(), yy.begin(), yy.end(),
        boost::make_function_output_iterator(
            [&diff](const double& d) { diff.push_back(&d); }
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I hoped for, and I did not find make_function_output_iterator when browsing around the boost docs. But, I have trouble compiling it with visual studio. https://godbolt.org/g/Qhtz3A

Comment: @JohanLundberg Could be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392919/boostfunction-output-iterator-constructed-from-lambda-function-is-not-assignab), maybe? Try saving the lambda to a `std::function` and see if it compiles.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you. According to answers there that is by design.

Comment: It isn't a problem [in all compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe1615a0a31b3918), though.

Answer (score 4):

There's probably something built in to boost, but here's my hacky attempt to write my own iterator:

```
template <typename T, typename FN>
struct transform_iterator {
    transform_iterator(T &t, FN fn)
      : _t{t}
      , _fn{std::move(fn)} { }

    transform_iterator<T, FN>& operator * () { return *this; }

    transform_iterator<T, FN>& operator ++ () { return *this; }

    template <typename V>
    transform_iterator<T, FN>& operator = (V const &v) {
        _t.push_back(_fn(v));
        return *this;
    }

    T &_t;
    FN _fn;
};
```

This will take a function and execute it whenever something tries to assign to the iterator (I *think* this is how things like `back_inserter` usually work).  A trivial helper function can create the iterators:

```
template <typename T, typename FN>
auto make_transform_iterator(T &t, FN fn) {
    return transform_iterator<T, FN>{t, std::move(fn)};
};
```

Lastly, `iterator_traits` needs to be specialized so `transform_iterator` will work with algorithms.

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T, typename FN>
    struct iterator_traits<transform_iterator<T, FN>> {
        using value_type = typename T::value_type;
    };
}
```

There are more types that need to be set in `iterator_traits`, but this was sufficient for my testing; your mileage will vary.

My `main` looks like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> xx{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> yy{1, 3, 5};
    std::vector<int> diff;

    auto ba = make_transform_iterator(diff, [](auto v) { return v + 10; });
    std::set_difference(std::begin(xx), std::end(xx),
                        std::begin(yy), std::end(yy),
                        ba);
    for(auto const &v: diff) {
        std::cout << v << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could expand this to work with generic output iterators instead of just types that support `push_back`.