# C++ Reuse Lambda as Compare function in `std::priority_queue`

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, priority-queue

When working with `std::priority_queue`, I tried to clear the contents of the priority queue like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::priority_queue;
using std::vector;

int main() {

    const auto comp = [](int a, int b) {
        return a > b;
    };

    auto a = priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)>(comp);

    a.push(10);
    a.push(9);
    a.push(8);

    // 3
    cout << a.size() << '\n';

    a = priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)>(comp);

    // 0
    cout << a.size() << '\n';

    return 0;

}
```

When compiling with Clang, I got an error:

```
In file included from tmp.cpp:1:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/queue:455:39: error: no viable overloaded '='
        {c = _VSTD::move(__q.c); comp = _VSTD::move(__q.comp); return *this;}
                                 ~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tmp.cpp:19:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, const (lambda at tmp.cpp:9:23)>::operator=' requested here
    a = priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(comp)>(comp);
      ^
tmp.cpp:9:23: note: candidate function (the implicit copy assignment operator) not viable: 'this' argument has type 'std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, const (lambda at tmp.cpp:9:23)>::value_compare' (aka 'const (lambda at tmp.cpp:9:23)'), but method is not marked const
    const auto comp = [](int a, int b) {
                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Why would this give me an error? And is there any way to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decltype(comp)` is a const type, `const auto comp`, that makes the `priority_queue` member variable storing `comp` to be constant, thus can't be re-assigned.

You might want

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, remove_cv_t<decltype(comp)>>(comp);
```

Or

```
auto comp = [](int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
};
```

The copy assignment operator for lambdas are implicitly deleted. The fix:

```
std::function<bool(int, int)> comp = [](int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
};
```

Comment: Now Clang is telling me that the copy assignment operator for lambdas are implicitly deleted. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Ohh, I forgot about it. No, use a regular function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481397/what-happens-when-a-type-containing-a-lambda-gets-assigned

Comment: It's working if you replace `auto` with `std::function<bool(int, int)>`

Comment: Is there any reason why the copy assignment operator is deleted for lambdas?

Comment: From C++20 lambda without capture has a defaulted copy/move assignment operator. https://compiler-explorer.com/z/x93YGWs1G

Comment: It seemed to be a standard defect, that was fixed in C++20.

Comment: Oh, I'm using `C++17`, also if I need captures is the only way `std::function`?

Comment: Yes, it seems so.